# How to detect route changes or match a route with a screen with react-navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

i am using react-navigation@1.5.0 in my app and with an SSO implementation.
The workflow is this:

- the app opens a log in button is presented
- once the user clicks on the log in button the app opens a Url on iOS mobile browser to the federated login server.
- on successful authentication the the user gets redirected to `myapp://authentication/<auth_code>` which correctly reopens my app.

unfortunately i can't detect any path/route changes.

my routes are setup like this:

```
export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      path: '/login',
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Log In'
      }
    },
    SsoHandler: {
      screen: SsoHandler,
      path: '/authentication/:authCode'
    },

    SignedIn: {
      screen: MainApp,
      path: '/'
    }
  }
);
```

the problem i am having is that i on the redirect from the federation service back to my iOS app 
it still opens the `Login` screen and i do not detect any route changes or prop changes so i could eventually navigate to the `SsoHandler`.

for some reason i would have expected the `StackNavigator` to detect the route and open the `SsoHandler` and not the `Login` on `/authentication/<auth_code>`.

what is the correct way to do this?

thank you,
andreas

Answer (score 1):

After digging into this I found out that i had to use `Linking.addEventListener` to listen to url changes through deep linking.

[React Native Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) has shows the necessary steps to achieve this.